Imputation of a categorical variable with constraints in Amelia R package
I would like to get some advice on imputing one variable with some bounds since i know what values it can be.
I tried the following:

a.out2 <- amelia(pushkin_impute, m = 5,
                 noms = "School", p2s = 0, max.resample=1000,
                 bounds=matrix(c(76,1,2), nrow = 1, ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))
table(a.out2$imputations[[2]]$School)

I imputes to all possible categories, not to the two I specified.
